# readLines equivalent when using Azure Data Lakes and R Server together

Tags: r, azure, azure-data-lake, microsoft-r

Using R Server, I want to simply read raw text (like readLines in base) from an **Azure Data Lake**. I can connect and get data like so:

```
library(RevoScaleR)

rxSetComputeContext("local")

oAuth <- rxOAuthParameters(params)
hdFS <- RxHdfsFileSystem(params)

file1 <- RxTextData("/path/to/file.txt", fileSystem = hdFS)
```

`RxTextData` doesn't actually go and get the data once that line is executed, it works as more of a symbolic link. When you run something like:

```
rxSummary(~. , data=file1)
```

*Then* the data is retrieved from the data lake. However, it is always read in and treated as a delimited file. I want to either:

1. Download the file and store it locally with R code (preferably not).
2. Use some sort of `readLines` equivalent to get the data from but read it in 'raw' so that I can do my own data quality checks.

Does this functionality exist yet? If so, how is this done?

EDIT: I have also tried:

```
returnDataFrame = FALSE
```

inside `RxTextData`. This returns a list. But as I've stated, the data isn't read in immediately from the data lake until I run something like `rxSummary`, which then attempts to read it as a regular file.

*Context: I have a "bad" CSV file containing line feeds inside double quotes. This causes RxTextData to break. However, my script detects these occurrences and fixes them accordingly. Therefore, I don't want RevoScaleR to read in the data and try and interpret the delimiters.*

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems unreal that Azure cannot do something this simple. If you can import nothing but CSV files, they should stop bragging about how Azure runs R!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a method of doing this by calling the Azure Data Lake Store REST API (adapted from a demo from Hadley Wickham's `httr` package on GitHub):

```
library(httpuv)
library(httr)

# 1. Insert the app name ----
app_name <- 'Any name'

# 2. Insert the client Id ----
client_id <- 'clientId'

# 3. API resource URI ----
resource_uri <- 'https://management.core.windows.net/'

# 4. Obtain OAuth2 endpoint settings for azure. ----
azure_endpoint <- oauth_endpoint(
    authorize = "https://login.windows.net/<tenandId>/oauth2/authorize",
    access = "https://login.windows.net/<tenandId>/oauth2/token"
    )

# 5. Create the app instance ----
myapp <- oauth_app(
  appname = app_name,
  key = client_id,
  secret = NULL
  )

# 6. Get the token ----
mytoken <- oauth2.0_token(
    azure_endpoint, 
    myapp,
    user_params = list(resource = resource_uri),
    use_oob = FALSE,
    as_header = TRUE,
    cache = FALSE
    )

# 7. Get the file. --------------------------------------------------------
test <- content(GET(
      url = "https://accountName.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=OPEN",
      add_headers(
        Authorization = paste("Bearer", mytoken$credentials$access_token),
        `Content-Type` = "application/json"
        )
  )) ## Returns as a binary body.

df <- fread(readBin(test, "character")) ## use readBin to convert to text.
```

Comment: I just wanted to verify. This requires making an Azure App through the Azure Portal?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with ScaleR functions like so. Set the delimiter to a character that doesn't occur in the data, and ignore column names. This will create a data frame containing a single character column which you can manipulate as necessary.

```
# assuming that ASCII 0xff/255 won't occur
src <- RxTextData("file", fileSystem="hdfs", delimiter="\x255", firstRowIsColNames=FALSE)

dat <- rxDataStep(src)
```

Although given that Azure Data Lake is really meant for storing big datasets, and this one seems to be small enough to fit in memory, I wonder why you couldn't just copy it to your local disk....

Comment: I'm not sure what data set you're referring to. But I will try this method, thanks.

Comment: I get the error `Error: reading text file: a row has more columns.` even for smaller and clean text files.